# Database Design best solution

Tags: database

i have a problem about db design. I am doing a blog application and i have 3 tables which names are `Record`, `Category` and `Tags`. In this case There are a lot of record and one record can related with `N` categories. And one category can relate with N tags. For example;

> Record 1--->N Category and  Category 1-->N Tag

What is the best db design in this scenario ?? Could you suggest any solution ?

Finally in the end of the project i want to do this,

```
 BlogRecord 
 ................
 ................
 Categories : Asp.net , JQuery
 Tags : Life Cyle,rooting,jquery selector,jQuery ajax
```

Comment: I don't follow, are you asking if you should use foreign keys?  You should use foreign keys.

Comment: i know this but how can i link these table effectively?

Comment: This is a classical M:N relationship.

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty basic example of database architecture. You have a `record`, which has a one-to-many relationship with both `tags` and `categories`. (If I understand right)

### One To Many

If you really need one-to-many relationships (I doubt that in this actually the case, however, see below), there is really one one sensible way to design this. When you have a one-to-many relationship, you have the "many" point to the "one". Your tables should look like this:

```
record:
   id, info, date_created, other_stuff

category:
   id, record_id, name, date_created, other_stuff

tag:
   id, record_id, info, other stuff
```

Pretty simple, both `tag` and `category` has a column called `record_id` which give the id of the record it belongs to.

One-to-many has a limitation. The 'many' can only point to 'one'. Just like the name. So if you have a one-to-many relationship where the records is 'one' and the category is the 'many', **each category can only have ONE record in it.** That doesn't really make sense for a category.

I think you might actually be looking for a many-to-many relationship for some of these:

### Many to Many

Ok, lets say you actually want a many-to-many relation between records and tags. Like the tag 'cool' can be attached to two different records, but each record can have many tag. Or maybe a record can be in many categories and a category can have many record. This seems like it would make more sense, and would be a 'many-to-many' relationship. It is a little harder, but still easy.

```
record:
     id, category_id, info, date_created, other_stuff

tag:
     id, info, other stuff
```

Notice I got rid of `record_id` on the tag, that is because it can attach to many different records, not just one. To do this, we need a whole table to map the many-to-many relationships:

```
records_to_tags
     record_id, tag_id
```

Now you fill your `records-to-tags` table with the relationships. You might have data like this:

```
record:
     1, "I'm the first record", "yay", 10/12/2014, asdf
     2, "I'm the second record", "woot", 10/13/2014, asdf

tags:
     1, "cool post"
     2, "awesome"

records-to-tags
     1, 1
     1, 2
     2, 2
```

You can see here that both records have the 'cool post' tag, but only the second one has the 'awesome' tag.

You can learn more about database relationships at this link: [http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561)

Comment: i don't want this db design i want to store only id's record and tags for every record. i don't want to create category and tag for every record

Comment: In this case one record can have one category. I want to 1-N relationship between record and category. If i have understood wrong i am sorry.

Comment: yes you are right i want to do this db design "You have a record, which has a one-to-many relationship with both tags and categories" and i want say is there any relationship must be required between category and tags?

Comment: then use a structure like given in the top, the one-to-many section.

Comment: between tags and category ?

Comment: If you really need one-to-many (make sure you understand the limitations) use a structure like the one in the first grey box. Where tag and category just 'point' to record. However, I believe you actually need many-to-many. Follow the link at the bottom of my post to learn more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47060/discussion-between-user990513-and-damien-black)

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the wheel? See the [Wordpress Database Design](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description). They've implemented this scenario using the following 3 tables and it's a very scalable design IMO.

1. wp_terms
2. wp_term_relationships
3. wp_term_taxonomy

`wp_terms` - The **categories** for both posts and links and the **tags** for posts are found within the `wp_terms` table.

`wp_term_relationships` - Posts are associated with **categories** and **tags** from the `wp_terms` table and this association is maintained in the `wp_term_relationships` table. The association of links to their respective **categories** are also kept in this table.

`wp_term_taxonomy` - This table describes the **taxonomy** (**category**, link, or **tag**) for the entries in the `wp_terms` table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a many-to-many relationship as many blog records can have an asp.net category and asp.net can have many blog records.  Same with Tags, so you'll probably need one or two pivot tables between the three (total of 5 tables).

Comment: and one category related with many tags. in this case  should i add any other table ?

Comment: I would.  as asp.net can have many tags (like life cycle and rooting), and many other categories can use the same tags. (also a many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i think my best solution is in above picture